# unable to retrieve all tables while scraping a webpage with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-parsing

I want to scrape the "Team Per Game Stats" table on http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1996.html, I've tried the following code

```
webpage <- getURL("http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1996.html")
tables <- readHTMLTable(webpage)
```

I've also tried to parse it

```
webpage <- getURL("http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_1996.html")
webpage <- readLines(tc <- textConnection(webpage))
pagetree <- htmlTreeParse(webpage, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
xpathApply(pagetree, "//table", xmlValue)
```

Both codes only give me the two tables under "Division Standings", whereas there should be more than 10 tables on that webpage.

Also, when I search "`//table[@id='team-stats-per_game']`" under inspect element on the webpage, it leads me right to the table I want, but R returns `NULL` when I try to find the same table with `xpathApply`.

what am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: that was a typo, I did use the quotation marks in the actual code @Hack-R

Comment: Right, I mean in your question. I went ahead and did it for you.

Comment: That website has been asked about several times. If you don't get the page in such a manner that it can run its JavaScript, it will hide the tables in HTML comments. [You can still parse them, though.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40665907/web-scraping-data-table-with-r-rvest?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, Thanks a lot! @alistaire